# FailedPrecondition: 400 Matching Engine is not supported in region europe-west4

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, vector-database

I am trying out matching engine on gcp and want to create an index. I see that the region I chose is not supported and I know that `us-central1` is a supported region.

However, due to legal reasons and policy, I cannot store data in the US. Is there a list of supported regions for Matching Engine (I could not find it). Alternatively, what EU region is supported for matching engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the regions where it is available are hiding from us but we can use the [Pricing Doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing#matchingengine) to get this info.

For instance the only available regions in EU are `europe_west1` and `europe_west9`.

In America the available regions are:

- `us_central1`
- `us_east1`
- `us_east4`
- `us_west1`
- `us_west4`
- `us_south1`
- `southamerica_east1`

And finally in Asia:

- `asia_south1`
- `asia_southeast1`
- `asia_northeast3`
- `australia_southeast1`

Comment: The pricing doc is a good call. That is the place to find the supported regions. Will keep that in mind for next time, thanks!